# using openid custom attributes within my environment

Tags: attributes, openid, custom-attributes

I with to setup a openid server which will support complex attributes that are not defined (http://www.axschema.org/types/) list or in experimental list. Attributes could be detailed information about his work like his reporting boss id, etc. My openid server and client both are within my control and are not supposed to be exposed to the internet.

Is it possible to create this environment within OpenId protocol? If yes, please suggest which servers support complex attributes if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute exchange protocol is pretty straightforward:

http://openid.net/specs/openid-attribute-exchange-1_0.html

You'll undoubtedly need to modify it to support these non-standard fields (doubly so because you're probably pulling the data from LDAP or some other database), but it shouldn't be hard.

(As for attribute exchange itself, almost all of the open-source implementations support this.)